# Refreshing Windows Media library by command line

Tags: command-line, windows-media-player

Many file download managers allow you to run a command after your download finishes.  Is there a command line to run a Windows Media Player 12 library refresh?  Videos don't show up in the available list on my PS3 until the library is refreshed.

Right now, I manually open Windows Media Player after the downloads finish, watch the bottom-right corner for the refresh to complete (ie. Update Complete), then close the player.  This works, but there has to be a better way.

Yes, I know [PS3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/) would do the trick, and I do use it when I need to transcode something, but WMP is running all the time, so I'd like to take advantage of it.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-media-player-libraries-how-to-auto-refresh/e93aaf60-aacc-4afc-9523-ed0baca27f00?tab=AllReplies#tabs). The problem described in the question looks similar to yours.

Comment: @amiregelz Tried the suggestions there, but unfortunately, I still had to manually open and close Windows Media Player to trigger a refresh.